# Change 2 finger tap to middle mouse button (Synaptics Precision touchpad) via regedit

Tags: windows-10, synaptics-touchpad

I recently bought a new Laptop (HP Envy x360, Intel i5 10th gen.) with a synaptics precision touchpad.

I just wanted to change 2 finger tap to middle mouse button. In in the win10 settings i can only choose to set 2fingertap to right click: yes or no. On my old laptop i had a dedicated synaptics tab in the advanced setting where I could change that, however I dont have that tab on my new device.

Here is what I tried so far:

1. reinstall drivers, install older drivers from HP and Synaptics website ... yada yada yada, nothing changed anything.

(because I thought it might be a software issue i returned the laptop. I bought the same laptop 1 month later with the new intel 11th gen., but everthing is the same and because this feature is absolutely crucial to me I continued the search for a solution)

2. as I said on my old computer i had the synaptics settings but when i changed it accordingly it didn't work anyways so had to install a 3rd party app (twofingerscroll.exe) which fixed the problem, but this program can't be installed on my new HP.
3. I found some synaptics programs in the Win10 store but they cant be installed either
4. now I tried to get a solution via the registry editor (however I am not experienced). I found an article which says that windows hides the synaptics settings which can be undone in the regedit:

https://7thzero.com/blog/unlock-hidden-synaptics-touch-pad-settings-windows-10

however i dont have the ' HideTPSettings ' on my device. Also I am scared that once I have the settings, it won't work anyway like on my old computer.

5. then I found an article where they successfully mapped 3fingertap to MMB via regedit:

[Windows 10 Synaptics no Control Panel and Middle Click](https://superuser.com/questions/954279/windows-10-synaptics-no-control-panel-and-middle-click/954318#954318)

I tried to adapt it to the 2fingertap, but wasn't successfull so far (also rebooting the machine after every try).

I just wanted to know if anyone can help me. I just know it must be possible because people have achieved far crazier modifications (https://www.reddit.com/r/Alienware/comments/5hyf3q/registry_hacks_to_enable_hidden_touchpad_features/) and this seems rather simple in comparison.

I am glad for any help, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

1. Run `regedit` and navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Synaptics\SynTP\TouchPad...`
2. Set item `2FingerTapAction` to the value of `4` (for middle button click)
3. Set item `MultiFingerTapFlags` to the value of `3`
4. Reboot

Note down well the values of the above items before changing them.
If the items do not exist, right-click the right part and select
*New > DWORD (32 bit) Value* to create them.

You might also find useful the
[TwoFingerScroll](http://forum.tabletpcreview.com/threads/twofingerscroll-v1-0-7-update-two-finger-scrolling-done-right-more.38405/)
application.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Harry!

I tried it, but unfortunately it still acted as RMB. I disabled the checkbox in the Win10 Touchpad settings where it says '2fingertap for RMB' and retried again, but still nothing. 

For the TwoFingerScroll application: as I said I used it for my last computer but on my new HP i get an error message when I try to install it (some class is not registered)

Is there a way to learn about regedit and what the values are mapped to?

Comment: I have not been able to locate any documentation about `2FingerTapAction`, and I did try. There's also no known method of intercepting the event with AutoHotKey and similar.

Comment: I was struggling with exactly the same issue and the Synaptics Mouse Properties just disabled the option to set the 2-finger-tap as middle button. So I followed the above regedit hack and went into Synaptics > ClickPad Settings and disabled and re-enabled the two-finger tap. When I opened up the config again, the disabled combobox was set to the Middle button (pulled from the registry I guess)